# Open Multiple Instances of Chrome Desktop App [Windows 7]

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I made a single-page web-app that my company is going to use.

To make it easier on the less tech-savy I'd like to pin the application to the Windows Taskbar. I found a round about way of doing this by:

1. Open desired website
2. Go to "More Tools" -> "Create Shortcut"
3. Go to the Apps page in Chrome and right click on the created app
4. Go to "Create Shortcuts" again, then select where you want the app (Desktop, Taskbar, etc.)

Now there is an app icon in the Taskbar, but there is seemingly no way to open multiple instances of this app? I tried right-clicking on it but it only gives me the option to open/close or remove from Taskbar.

Comment: Why not set it as a default bookmark in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution right as I was writing this question *(Hurray rubber duck debugging!!)*

Once you open one instance of your created Taskbar app (as stated in my question) you simply need to rightclick on the Taskbar app and then click on the first option that it gives you. The options are as follows:

1. [App Name]
2. Unpin Program From Taskbar
3. Close Window

Simply click on "[App Name]" and this will open another instance of your desired app in another separate window.

For Desktop created shortcuts simply double click the app as many times as you need windows.